AudienceStream: set manually a attribute to test it with trace
I am using Tealium AudienceStream for a project; I need to check if a user has made a purchase in the last 30 days and, if not, send an email.
I have twp visitor attributes: "Last purchase date" (date) and "Days since last purchase" (number) and also I have an audience "Old purchases" with the rule "If Days since last purchase > 30".
I would like to test this, so I am wondering if, using Trace, I can manually set "Last purchase date" to a date older than 30 days ago to see if everything works.
Is this possible?
I manually set the value in Tealium iQ but I cannot see any value set.

Is this a programming-related question, if so, then please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

How is the attribute "Last purchase date" enriched?
Assuming there is an enrichement like:
Set:

current timestamp
When:
tealium_event = purchase

or similar...
We can add an additional enrichement, something like:
Set:

from event_stream attribute "my_date"(string) with format "yyyy-MM-dd"
When:
tealium_event = my_test_purchase_date

This is can then be tested from any API client (no need to depend on the website).
I like Postman (but any works). Here's a sample payload:
endpoint: https://collect.tealiumiq.com/event
payload:
{
    "tealium_account":"....your account....", 
    "tealium_profile":"....your profile....",  
    "tealium_trace_id":"....your traceid....",

    "tealium_event":"my_test_purchase_date", 
    "my_date": "2024-07-20"
}

